# Can't get anything to run in my ApplicationEvents.vb file

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get some file directory stuff writen upon initalization/startup of my program. I got it running once but then it broke when I tried again with different code for more stuff. I have no idea why

Here is the code inside of my ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices
Imports System.IO
Imports System



Namespace My
    Module Module1

        Sub createDirectory()
            Dim path As String = "c:\MyTest.txt"

            ' Create or overwrite the file.
            Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: You should probably override `OnStartup()` and do *something* there.

Comment: Oh I see, yep I'm an idiot. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see any Application Events.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to have a startup event.

```
namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            Dim path As String = "c:\MyTest.txt"

            ' Create or overwrite the file.
            Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```